# Invoking script on Listening the requestcycle start and removing the script at the cycle end

Tags: web-deployment, wicket-6

What all possible way to call JS or CSS in onBeginRequest() and onEndRequest() of AbstractRequestCycleListener class of Wicket? 
Actually, i want to perform some action at client side using JS or Css at every request made and undo the action on the request end, I want to do this at application level and not component specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily for Ajax requests. See AjaxCallListener's `onBeforeSend()` and `onComplete()` methods. Documentation is available at https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_ajax_request_attributes_and_call_listeners

For normal (non-Ajax) requests this is not that trivial because the complete page reloads and thus your JS/CSS is unloaded with Page1 and reloaded with Page2.

Comment: Thank you.  But i want to make the changes  in application level. AjaxCallListener can be added to a component and not to the whole application by adding it in the base page as it needs updateAjaxAttributes(). I need some generic solution using which i can invoke JS(Spinner) at every ajax request made and remove the JS(Spinner) at request end. I tried using getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId() of IAjaxIndicatorAware but to my knowledge i can only use this to invoke some Css.  Please suggest idea to do this.

Comment: See WebApplication.getAjaxRequestTargetListeners(). With this you can add it for every Ajax request. Also in the same documentation look for global Ajax listeners in JavaScript.